# Show a lot of images with really low memory using in C#?

Tags: c#, image, memory, picturebox

I have a form in which I dynamically create 8 `PictureBox`es in a `Panel` in which I show 8 different images, one every `PictureBox`. Images are 50Kb Jpeg.
The problem is that I want to allow user to see also 300 pictures,that's like 38 panels, but every time I **LOAD** images into `PictureBox`es my program uses 5-7Mb of Ram memory **MORE**.( I see it from the Windows' task manager)
How can i reduce that increment? My Pictures aren't that big, I only want to show a preview, i don't care about quality.
Here is how i CREATE `PictureBox`es:

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
  Panel pan = new Panel();
  PictureBox pic1 = new PictureBox();
  pic1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
  pic1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(208, 5);
  pic1.Name = "panel" + ctr.Count().ToString() + "pictureBox1";
  pic1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
  pic1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
  ///
  /// Same thing other 7 times with differents name and location
  ///      
  pan.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 55);
  pan.Name = "panel" + ctr.Count().ToString();
  pan.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1088, 129);
  pan.TabIndex = 0;
  pan.AllowDrop = true;
  pan.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLight;
  pan.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;           
  pan.Controls.Add(pic1);
  ///
  /// Same thing other 7 times 
  ///        
  this.Controls.Add(pan);
  }
```

And here is how i fill them:

```
void buttonClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files= Directory.GetFiles("mylocalpath");
        foreach(string x in files)
        {
            string imgIndex= x.Remove(0,x.LastIndexOf("_")+1).Remove(1);
            PictureBox pic=pictureBox1; 
            //I get it everytime from imgIndex and sender's parent,
            //too much code to show now
            pic.ImageLocation = x;
        }

    }
```

Comment: First, do not trust the taskmanager!

Comment: Try overriding `OnPaint` and `OnRefresh`, so you can load an image, draw it, and forget about it. Only suitable for static unhidden images.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore the IDisposable interface in .NET for a very long time.  Many .NET programmers never call the Dispose() method on disposable objects and never use the *using* statement and their programs work just fine.  The garbage collector keeps the program humming along, calling the finalizer on such classes to clean up.

But the Image and Bitmap classes are special.  They are very thin managed classes wrappers around GDI+, an unmanaged api.  Images can use *lots* of unmanaged memory to store the pixel data, many megabytes on large images.  Combine that with a program that doesn't otherwise allocate enough managed objects to trigger a garbage collection and you've got a fat piggy problem.

You **must** dispose images after you are done using them to avoid this problem.  That's a bit difficult to do when you use the PictureBox.ImageLocation property, the PictureBox class loads the image using a worker thread.  It cannot itself dispose the previous image, it cannot know if the image might be used somewhere else.  You have to help:

```
    foreach(string x in files)
    {
        string imgIndex = x.Remove(0,x.LastIndexOf("_")+1).Remove(1);
        PictureBox pic = pictureBox1; 
        //...
        if (pic.Image != null) pic.Image.Dispose();
        pic.Image = null;
        pic.ImageLocation = x;
    }
```

Or use the Image.FromFile() method instead so you don't have to look at the empty picture box.

Comment: This can be easily combined with virtualization. Good to point out `using` and `Dispose`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps UI virtualization can help you.

Do you want to show all those pictureboxes at once?

As I understood your question, you only want to show 8 of them at once.

Please have a look at the following article [UI / Data virtualization](http://bunjeeb.com/2010/10/30/ui-data-virtualization/)

and especially the [virtualizing panel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2006/02/16/533870.aspx)

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain well, I want to show a lot of images simultaneously, grouped by 8 but always a lot simultaneously.
Something like 80 panel, that means 640 images.
However, i don't know what UI / Data virtualization is, so i'll study it , thanks for now :D

Comment: then the virtualizing panel is your choice

Answer (score 1):

Displaying the pictures is handled by the OS (the GDI subsystem), and this introduces a known memory inefficiency: The image is internally rendered to a bitmap in its original size, using a substantial amount of memory, this bitmap is then scaled down only for display.

Your best bet is to create small preview images and display those instead.

Also keep in mind, that you are working in a garbage collected environment: Not all the memory you see in Task Manager is really used, if memory pressure builds up the GC will more aggressivly return memory to the system - in fact your application is likely to use less memory if run on a system with less available memory.

Comment: Those are quite interesting informations, I didn't know it was handled by OS...But I already tried to create and load only little thumbs, but nothing changes. I understand that taskmanager is big liar sometimes, so I'll take a look, thank you!